# best method moving data between many table

Tags: sql-server

I have an Invoice that I need to move from Pending Sales
to a Sale Journal, at the end of year to a Master Sale Journal.
Old quotes get moved to a Quote Archive as well.  Quotes and Invoices
from the Sale Journal can be moved back to Pending Sales.

I want to build a class that I can pass the source and destination tables
to and move the invoice in and out of.

I have never done a Stored Procedure or pass the adapterTable to a procedure
either.

I am not sure what is the best method to approach a seedy solution is.

I am thinking a stored procedure is the way to go, but how to do a Fill and Insert?

Ideas? code examples?

```
Started playing with this, but not even close to a good sstart

SqlDataAdapter daPASQS = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + "VF_PasQS" + " WHERE (calendar_year = " + year + ") and (inv_no_  =" +
                                                                         InvNo + ") and (s = " + Series + "}", pasps);
DataSet dsPASQS = new DataSet();

daPASPR.TableMappings.Add("vf_PASQS", "invNo");
daPASPR.Fill(dsPASQS, "invNo");
BindingSource myBinding = new BindingSource(dsPASQS, "invNo");

pasps.Close();

int invNo = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in dsPASQS.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    invNo = (Int32)row["invNo"];
}
```

Thanks,

Jerry

---

Been playing with the following,

```
        string str = "select * into VF_PASPS " +
                     "FROM         vf_PASQS " +
        "WHERE (calendar_year = '" + year + "') AND (inv_no_ = '" + InvNo + "') AND (s = '" + Series + "')";
```

but only creats a NEW TABLE.  I need to add/append to an existing table

Thanks,

Jerry

Comment: Is there a reason you are moving data between tables instead of just setting flags to indicate a status for the sale/order/quote?

Comment: Been playing with the following, 

            string str = "select * into VF_PASPS " +
                         "FROM         vf_PASQS " +
            "WHERE (calendar_year = '" + year + "') AND (inv_no_ = '" + InvNo + "') AND (s = '" + Series + "')";


but only creats a NEW TABLE.  I need to add/append to an existing table

Comment: Are you trying to do a select into?  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SqlBulkCopy class